# How to design a circular reference to a single database table with an added relationship?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, data-modeling

I'm not sure how best to phrase the question, but essentially I have a table of contacts, and instead of doing the typical -- a contact has a reference to a table with spouse information, and a table with children, I want each of those people to be a contact, but then define a relationship between those contacts (brother, sister, child, spouse, etc.). So the contacts would exist in a single table, but I'm having trouble determining how best to define the relationship based upon their contact id and the relationship type. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `CONTACTS` table

- `contact_id`, pk

### `CONTACT_RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_CODE` table

- `contact_relationship_type_code`, pk
- `description`

### `CONTACTS_RELATIONS` table

- `parent_contact_id`, pk, foreign key to `CONTACTS` table
- `child_contact_id`, pk, foreign key to `CONTACTS` table
- `contact_relationship_type_code`, foreign key to `CONTACT_RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_CODE` table

If you see the need to support multiple relationship types to a pair of people, add the `CONTACTS_RELATIONS.contact_relationship_type_code` column to the composite primary key

Comment: Careful not to over-normalize this data.  You could just have a contact_relations table with a relationship_code field.

Comment: I would have made the PK of the contacts table compound: parent_contact_id, contact_id, relationship_type_code.  These three ought to be unique. 

Also, there's a little wrinkle in the table.  For symmetric relationships such as siblings, there have to be two entries in the table, or else your queries have to be more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: If I understand the CONTACTS_RELATIONS table correctly, the parent_contact_id is the contact_id of one individual in the relationship, while the contact_id is the contact_id (in CONTACTS) of the second individual in the relationship. Is that correct? Also, why make those primary keys? Why not a contacts_relations_id as a PK and AI, and then index all three? Just curious.

Comment: My mistake.  The PK in CONTACTS_RELATIONSHIP is a compound key.  I misread the solution.

@hal10001,  the primary reason for declaring a primary key is to ensure that each primary key is unique and that no part of a primary key is missing.  You get these benefits if you declare a compound primary key for a relationship.  

A lot of designers always add a simple PK as the first column of every table.  My experience says that this pattern usually costs more than it's worth, except for entity tables.  But other people evidently have other opinions.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a self join, it is pretty common and fairly easy to provide the functionallity you mention above. Take a look at this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Self-join).

Answer (score 0):

Just implement an intersect table with four columns - key, contactid #1, contact id#2, and relationship.

Why do it this way? Because a contact can have several relationships.

Comment: Perfect - and not only can they have multiple relationships - but those relationships can have their own attributes like start & stop dates (important for spouses, brother's in law, etc), statuses, etc.  It's a good way to ensure your design has the flexibility to grow without much work.  Note that this just supports binary relationships tho - so if you want other kinds of relationships (like 'households') you'll have to do it in steps.